# Proof that $\zeta(11) > \frac{\pi^3}{31}$.

Tags: inequality, riemann-zeta, pi

I would like to prove $\zeta(11)>\pi^3/31$, where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. They differ in the fourth decimal place. I suppose this could be 'proven' by simply comparing known numerical approximations for the two constants, which are accurate beyond the fourth decimal place, but that is no fun.

> The first step would be to show whether $\pi^3 <31$ or $\pi^3 > 31$ while hoping $\pi^3 \neq 31$. It is not too difficult to prove the second, **so I am only asking** for help proving $\zeta(11) > \pi^3/31$ with the assumption that $\pi^3/31>1$.

I initially hoped this inequality would spring from some other properties of the zeta function, though odd powers of $\pi$ are hard to come by. One can show that
$$-\frac{2^{11}\pi^{10}\zeta'(-10)}{3628800} = \zeta(11)$$
Which is lovely and probably useless to solving my problem. I tried to use the fact that $\zeta(x)$ is strictly decreasing on the domain I am concerned with, though I have not made much progress as I cannot say much about $\zeta(11)$ by itself as there is no known closed form, and manipulating $\zeta(12)$ and $\zeta(10)$ to obtain the $\pi^3$ term leaves me $\pi$ multiples of the zeta function, which I have no idea how to handle.

Comment: I mean you can also make a rigorous proof just with numerics

Comment: To clarify, I'm guessing you're looking looking for something cute like the semi-famous $\int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{22}7 - \pi$ proof that $\pi < \frac{22}7$?

Comment: @DarkMalthorp yes, that is what I’m getting at. I will clarify this in the post when I am not on mobile.

Comment: $\zeta(11) > 1 + 1/2^{11} > \pi^3/31$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, since $\zeta(2k)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi^{2k}$, it would perhaps be more natural to consider that $\zeta(2k+1)>c \pi^{2k}$ for a rational $c>0$, and not $\pi^3$.

So, for $k=5$ this would be, say,
$$
\zeta(11)> \frac{\pi^{10}}{93648}.
$$

And as you said, we could use the following formula here.

$$ \zeta(2k+1)=\frac{(-1)^k2^{2k+1}}{(2k)!}\pi^{2k}\zeta'(-2k). $$